# Project documentation repository

Tags: document-management, documentation-viewer

When preparing a development webtools server (Sonar, Redmine, Jenkins...) a need arose to prepare a storage solution for documentation alongside these tools. While in ideal world we would store everything in a wiki, docbooks, LateX, Javadocs or other easily-versionable and searchable format, we don't have that luxury. What we have instead is piles upon piles of MS Word .DOCX files.

Ideal software for this task should have as many of the following features as possible:

- is web-based and allows download of documents via HTTP/S
- is possible to be hosted locally in the company intranet, not somewhere externally in the Internet (this one is a must)
- supports storing multiple versions of the same (binary) file, such as .DOCX
- has a tag-based search tool and directory/file tagging
- has a content-based search tool of MS Word files, possibly via [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org)
- allows access control via permissions (to individual files and/or directories)

We considered several tools for this, such as [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org), [Redmine](http://redmine.org), [Dokuwiki](http://dokuwiki.org) and just regular FTP/SMB hosting. All of them are lacking some of above features, though, and we're considering if there isn't something out there that would be a better fit.

What are your preferred solutions for documentation/versioned binary files storage?

Comment: I just found out that my question may be a duplicate of this one: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26705/a-secure-private-searchable-online-document-storage-service . Maybe ownCloud is worth another look.

Comment: Not a duplicate thanks to the tagging requirement.

Comment: As you say "ideally Wiki", Atlassians [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) comes to mind. It has the capability of importing Word documents into its wiki. I'm not very familiar with it (just had a short contact at a customer's site), hence only a comment and suggestion for something to look at.

Answer (score 2):

[Alfresco](https://www.alfresco.com/alfresco-community-download) has all of the features you have listed:

- web-based: Yes there is a web interface, among other interfaces like FTP and CMIS
- Allows download of documents via HTTP/S: Yes, and upload too
- Possible to be hosted locally in the company intranet: Yes, download and install on your own hardware
- supports storing multiple versions: Yes, history is available for any file
- directory/file tagging: Yes. tags are user-defined. There is also a concept of "categories", which are admin-defined.
- tag-based search tool: Yes you can search by tag
- content-based search tool of MS Word files: Yes, full-text search of MS Office, PDF, LibreOffice, etc
- allows access control via permissions: Yes, with groups/roles/etc, very flexible

Alfresco is free and open source.

[image: Alfresco 5 search facets]